# HTTP2 client-side support in Akka EventSource streaming API?

Tags: java, akka, server-sent-events, http2

How can I use the [Akka EventSource Connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/sse.html?_ga=2.259384783.438447787.1525448128-1958069919.1525448128?_ga=2.259384783.438447787.1525448128-1958069919.1525448128) to stream data from an HTTP2 source, such as the one [here](https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange)?  I've heard that Akka supports HTTP2, but I can only find server-side documentation for enabling the feature, and the [HttpProtocols](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka-http/current/?_ga=2.120852941.435713144.1525448280-1958069919.1525448128)  class only lists support for HTTP1 and HTTP1.1.  Running the example code with the v2 source results in `400 BAD REQUEST` results.  How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that [Akka HTTP currently only supports HTTP/2 at the server side](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1883).

That said, however, many servers will support both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 side by side, and the example you give is no exception: it will work fine with HTTP/1.1 as you can test with for example `curl -v --http1.1 https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange`.

Did you run into any particular problems trying to use the [Alpakka Server-Sent Events (SSE) Connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/sse.html) with https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange ?